# How to save and display an image from expo-image-picker that doesn't rely on uri

Tags: react-native, image, expo-image-picker

This has been driving me crazy for several days now. I can display an image from a URI from expo-image-picker. But the image will not display on anyone else's device. How do I save the image (I have a nodejs backend with express server and postgresql database), so that I can retrieve the image and display it across all devices?

I've tried blobs. I've tried base64. I can't get anything to work. At this point I have hundreds of tabs open and I don't even know what I'm supposed to be doing anymore. What is the way to do this?